# Can't open websites (Chrome, Firefox) using Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, firefox

Since two days it is not possible anymore on my PC to open websites with firefox via Selenium WebDriver (Java, Maven, IntelliJ). A blank page is opened in a new firefox window and nothing happens. I can access the specified website manually in the firefox window that is opened.

This is the code I am using for creating the webdriver (the profile SELENIUM exists; I created it manually):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
return new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

And to open pages I am using:

```
driver.get(myURL);
```

The error message from IntelliJ is:

> SZgNd84ad1sbgGXU5f5p+46dwuqwWXX8hUp4lAPBZwEAAA0DAAANAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALfGQwB4dWxzdG9yZS5qc29uUEsFBgAAAABGAEYAnRUAAFnIQwAAAA (and some million more letters) == does not equal undefined"] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Today Chrome also stopped working, it only shows "Not secure" next to the URL and data; in the URL bar. 
Is there any way to find out what caused this and how this can be fixed? 
I am using the latest version of selenium (defined in pom.xml) Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133, Firefox 45.4.0.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: make sure you are using latest chromedriver 2.28. with chrome v57 plus try to upgrade your FF and use geckodriver 0.15 with selenium 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in a previous project, so basically what happens is that all this is caused by incompatibility between Selenium and Firefox/Chrome versions, but not by any one specific version number. So what you really want is to be 1-2 driver versions behind the newest, if your WebDriver is on the latest version. Otherwise, roll the Firefox/Chrome version back even further if your WebDriver is older, or upgrade Webdriver.

Other options is to use [FF profiles](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/)/Chrome [preferences](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities). This is an example that was working back then:

```
FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();
//FirefoxProfile prof = profile.getProfile("default");
//prof.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage", pageUrl);
//prof.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url", pageUrl);
//prof.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional", pageUrl);
prof.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
prof.setPreference("toolkit.telemetry.reportingpolicy.firstRun", false);
```

You can try other combinations of those settings and see which one will work for you.